# Java/Android Change data in a ListView populated by a ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have an issue which I can't seem to solve. I have a `ListView`, this `ListView` contains an object (`IndividualRow`). this `IndividualRow` has 3 values which are displayed in `textviews` and in a switch. These `IndividualRows` are stored in an `ArrayList`, but then I got stuck.

I want to press on 1 of the `TextViews` (which is displaying a temperature), when I press it, it should automatically add 1.

Now the problem is that I don't know how to implement this. I tried several things but I cound't figure it out. I don't specifically want code, but I'd like to know what I should do, so I'll not copy past and don't learn from it. This is my code so far.

(I have a custom adapter so that the ListView displays my rows accordingly, i can include it here if you want)

list_item.xml (this is how a row looks like)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="14dp"
android:paddingBottom="14dp" >

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:height="30dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textOff="@string/Off"
    android:textOn="@string/On"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp" />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tijd"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"        
    android:gravity="right"
    android:clickable="true"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/temperatuur"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:clickable="true"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GradenCelcius"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the IndividualRow code

```
//holds values for each individual row
  public  class IndividualRow {
//instance variables
private  String  tijd;
private  int  temperatuur;
private  boolean onoroff2;

//constructor > what an individual row needs to be an individual row
public IndividualRow(String data1,int data2, boolean onoroff){
tijd = data1;
temperatuur = data2;
onoroff2 = onoroff;
}

//sends value of tijd
public String getString1(){
    return tijd;
}

//sends value of temperatuur
public String getString2(){
    String x = Integer.toString(temperatuur);
    return x;
}

//sends value of switch state, so on or off (on = true, off = false)
public boolean getBoolean() {
    return onoroff2;
}

//probably should add setString1 and so on here right?
}
```

And than here is my fragment which should operate it all

```
public class SettingTimeFragment extends Fragment{

//Instance Variables
private List<IndividualRow> items = new ArrayList<IndividualRow>();
private CustomAdapter adapter;
private ListView rowListView;
private String tijd = "0:00";
private int temperatuur = 15; 
private boolean onoroff = true;

//creates the SettingTimeFragment
public static final SettingTimeFragment newInstance(){
    SettingTimeFragment f = new SettingTimeFragment();
    return f;
}

//providing it's layout
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment 
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_time_fragment, container, false);
}

//creates the content of SettingTimeFragment
@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    items.add(new IndividualRow(tijd, temperatuur, onoroff));// add initial row

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item, items); // create new CustomAdapter
    rowListView=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rowListView); // find rowListView
    rowListView.setAdapter(adapter); //attach adapter to rowListView
}


//creates menu on top of the screen
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.setting_time_fragment_menu, menu);
}

//finds each individual button in menu and handles click events
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.additionbutton:                      
            addRow(new IndividualRow(tijd, temperatuur, onoroff));
            return true;           
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//adds a new IndividualRow
public void addRow(IndividualRow newRow) {
       items.add(newRow);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //updates adapter that there is new information to display
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am android newbie. But I will try what I would have done/did for almost similar situation. 
First of all , I am not aware of the `listview` that you are talking about in example. I can see you using `textview`, and I doubt if that is clickable by default. I have used android list view like this which can be updated on every click:

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/item_list" />
```

This is how I created adapter:

```
  final ArrayAdapter<ContentData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ContentData>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

and this is how I would update the `listview` ( `longClick` example, you can use `OnClick`) :

```
 lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int position, long id) {
            //update your list and perform your actions                    
               //notify your adapter about the changes if required
            return true;
        }
    });
```

You will probably need to research on how to use `values.get()`  in above method. Basically about what `position` and `id` represents in above method and what `adapter` and `view` can provide.

I hope it did not confuse you. The above sample is from actual code I implemented for learning purpose, so It may not be the best solution.